# New branch needs to have submodule's default branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

I've seen several similar questions, but I either I wasn't implementing the solutions correctly or they don't actually address my issue.

Background:
We have a desktop app that can access a website (that we own) via a webview. Because we sometimes change the way the app/webview interacts with the website, we have the website's repository as a submodule for the app so we can easily coordinate the javascript with app functions. The website itself is independent from the app and can be changed in other ways for other functions. (Company policy is to not touch the javascript that belongs to other teams when you are changing stuff for your own team. Thus far this policy is being upheld just fine. Yay.) The website repo has a release branch that gets pushed to a release server when the teams agree that it can be, and a default branch that gets pushed to a testing server whenever it gets a new commit.

The problem:
Since sometimes other teams are updating the website, we need to make sure that *when we make a new feature branch* from the default branch for our app, we always get the latest commit to the default branch for the website, so that we start with the latest code there. Once we've gotten that commit, we need to be able to make a feature branch in the website's repo and commit it to our app's feature branch. We need to be able to keep the app feature branch tied to the website feature branch, and not have it revert back to the default branch when we pull or merge from another branch. This needs to happen even if the website's feature branch has a different name than the app's feature branch. The needs to work both when the branch is made by a git client and when it is made on Bitbucket.

I have tried setting `branch=default` in the appropriate place in the .gitmodules file, I have tried using `git submodule update --remote` and several other things that I can't remember now in the fog of trying to sort through all the different sets of advice available on similar topics here in StackOverflow. Nothing that I have seen yet has hit this exact solution. I thought I had it until I made a new branch and submodule branch and did an update and then the submodule changed to the default branch. Obviously I did something wrong, but I'm not sure where it was. I haven't tried Bitbucket Pipelines yet, as I have no experience with it and don't want to open that can of worms unless I'm sure that's where I need to be.

TL;DR: I need to make sure that new branches on a repository always start with the latest commit of a submodule's default branch without making it impossible to associate the new branch with a submodule's branch.

Alternatively, I would be willing to accept a solution where the app's default branch gets an automated commit to the latest commit of the website's branch whenever it changes. That might cause extra unnecessary builds, but it will be a small price to pay for making sure we don't build new features on an old version of the website.

Apologies if I haven't hit the exactly correct terminology above, as my geek focus is not in Git. I'm happy to update to clarify if needed.

*Edit to fix confusing typo.

Answer (score 1):

The branch name stored in the `.gitmodules` file is almost worthless.  For the most part Git will just ignore it.  There is *one* place it's used, and it *might* work for your case, but it requires explicit action on your part.  I'll get to that in just a moment, but first, remember:

- It's the *commit* in the superproject that specifies which submodule *commit* will get checked out.
- This specification is through the hash ID stored in the *gitlink* entity that has the submodule's name.
- To emphasize this point: **In submodules, only hash IDs matter: branch names are *not used*.**  Git finds these hash IDs via gitlinks.  The only way that a branch name is (very rarely) used is to *find* a hash ID, so as to store it in an updated gitlink.

For example, assuming your superproject is cloned via `git clone <url> superproj` and you then `cd superproj` and run `git checkout --recursive <commit-or-branch>` and the submodule is named `path/to/sub` and the commit you've selected *in the superproject* has `path/to/sub` as a gitlink with hash ID `a123456` in it, the superproject Git will run:

```
(cd path/to/sub && git switch --detach a123456)
```

as part of the `git checkout --recursive`.

> I need to make sure that new branches on a repository always start with the latest commit of a submodule's default branch ...

A new branch in the superproject starts with an existing commit in the superproject.  That existing commit has an existing gitlink, so that's the gitlink you have, and that's the submodule commit you get.  It's quite irrelevant what's stored in any branch name in the submodule: the *only thing that matters* at this point is the hash ID stored in the gitlink.  The gitlink is part of a commit, so—like any part of any commit—it literally *cannot* be changed.  All you can do is make a *new* commit.

So, that's precisely what you must do now: make a new commit.  The new commit will contain a *new* gitlink.  And if you tell Git to do it, that new gitlink will store a *different* hash ID.  So *now*—now that the new branch name exists in the superproject, because you've created a new branch name—the *first thing you'll do is make a new commit*, or at the very least, *prepare* to make a new commit (you don't actually have to make it yet), with a new gitlink value.

#### Putting the correct value in the new gitlink

Now we get to the real answer, which is where the almost (but not quite) worthless branch name stored in a `.gitmodules` file comes in.  If *at this point* you run:

```
git submodule update --remote
```

then instead of running:

```
git rev-parse :path/to/sub
```

to get the hash ID (which reads it out of the superproject index), the superproject Git software will run:

```
(cd path/to/sub && git fetch origin && git rev-parse origin/$branch:path/to/sub)
```

(assuming `origin` is the correct remote; substitute in the correct remote if needed).  The `git fetch` step calls up the repository that `git submodule update --init` cloned initially,<sup>1</sup> which obtains any new commits from them and updates all the `origin/*` remote-tracking names.  The `git rev-parse` step then figures out which hash ID is stored in the gitlink under the `origin/$branch` name, for the path `path/to/sub`, which is the path for the submodule in question.  The `$branch` here is taken from the value derived from the default branch for the submdoule.

So—assuming that all of the complicated Rube Goldberg apparatus here has not gone awry already—this extracts the hash ID that you wanted.  That hash ID is then fed to the:

```
(cd path/to/sub && git switch --detach $hash)
```

operation that puts the submodule into detached-HEAD state on the desired commit.

**The submodule is still in detached-HEAD state.**  It is not on any branch.  The idea here is that you're not going to do any work *in* the submodule, you're just *using* it.

If you want the *submodule* repository to be *on a branch*, you're basically out of luck: to get that, you must do your own

```
(cd path/to/sub && git switch $branch)
```

You *can* use `git submodule foreach` to achieve this, but you must write at least a little bit of code (to retrieve the `$branch` setting that you'd like to use).

Whether `git submodule update --remote` is sufficient, or whether you need to do your own `cd path/to/sub && git fetch && git switch $branch` or whatever, you must do that.  Then, back in the *superproject*, you run one more command:

```
git add path/to/sub
```

This stores the new `HEAD` hash ID that is now present *in* the submodule into the gitlink entity in the index in the superproject, from which a `git commit` in the superproject will create the next commit.

You can now update any other files in the superproject you like, `git add` them as usual, and then run `git commit` to make a new commit.  This new commit will store, in its gitlink, the raw hash ID of the submodule.  Note that if you make any new *commits* **in** the submodule, you will need to `git add path/to/sub` again to update the gitlink entity in the superproject index.  You'll presumably also want to `git push` those new commits to whatever repository the superproject Git clones.

(This is all rather messy, and you now know one of the reasons people call these sob-modules.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that this depends on the URL stored under the name `origin`, which happened at the time the superproject Git did the `git clone` operation, which was probably on some other commit.  So this doesn't use what's in the `.gitmodules` file that is in place in the superproject working tree *now*, but rather what was *copied out of* the `.gitmodules` file that was in place then.

Comment: So, is there a way to configure a repository so that it runs `git submodule update --remote` whenever `git branch` and/or `git checkout -b` is run?

Comment: @clnoel: No. You would have to write a tiny script to use *instead of* those commands.